# multiple match on condition after aggregate lookup in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
db.setting.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      status: true,
      deleted_at: 0,
      _id: {
        $in: ids
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "admin",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "admin_id",
      as: "data"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "data.createdAt": {
        $gte: new Date("2020-01-01")
      }
    }
  },

])
```

I am getting one value but even expected multiple data which are greater then equal to 01 jan 2020. How can I fix it please guide thanks

Comment: Please post sample input document (of both collections) _and_ a sample expected output.

Comment: mongoplayground.net/p/TA-f89ECBDk numberOfRecord : Count should be base on: $gte: new Date("2020-01-01")

Comment: Instead of the `$match` stage use a `$addFields` stage _and_ use the [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) operator on the array field `"data.createdAt"`.

Comment: TRIED didn't get much help

Comment: What have you tried? Was there an error?

Comment: No error but did not get data can you make it for me ?

Comment: Post your tried query in the post.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/JtFEBeKDs4O

Comment: In this code  `$gte: [ "$$item", new Date("2020-01-01") ]`, the comparison should be between the _element_ (`$$elmt`) and the date.

Comment: It doesn't make any differen

Comment: Try `"$$elt.createdAt"`.

Comment: I did try nothing works you can try with playground

Comment: It is just a  `$filter` **without** the `$map` (see my previous comments).

Answer (score 0):

You have to unwind the result after lookup to perform `$match`.

```
db.setting.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      status: true,
      deleted_at: 0,
      _id: {
        $in: ids
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "admin",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "admin_id",
      as: "data"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$data"}
  {
    $match: {
      "data.createdAt": {
        $gte: new Date("2020-01-01")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        status: { "$first": "$status" },
        deleted_at: { "$first": "$deleted_at" }, //You can project more 
        data: { "$push": "$data" }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Yes my bad only one record I see after unwind

Comment: Yes it is show only if I keep unwind if I remove it does not return any result

Comment: You have to group the unwind data once you get the matched document

Comment: wait I will add group pipeline

Comment: Updated. Check it out

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/TA-f89ECBDk 

numberOfRecord : Count should be base on:  $gte: new Date("2020-01-01")

Comment: Please help when you're back